# Creating Spatial Map Series with Overview Map showing changing location of Main Map Frame in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, map-series, map-overviews

I am trying to create a layout with two map frames. One map frame showing details in M 1:5000 the other one showing an overview map in M 1:50.000. I would like to link both views and show the extent of the detailed map frame automatically in the overview map frame. It is a map series of more than 6000 maps.

In ArcMap it was possible to fix the scale of the overview map, and dynamically highlight the extent of the other data frame. Everything can be exported to PDF with Data Driven Pages.

How do I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Have you studied the help file on [extent indicators](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/extent-indicators.htm)?

Comment: Does “M 1:5000” mean “Map at 1:5000” or something else?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you know how to configure a Map Series, but just not how to configure a Layout for a Map Series which is to have the extent of its Main map frame indicated on its Overview map frame.

The steps that I use to configure a layout for that are:

1. Insert a map, which I rename to be Main Map, and configure it with the layers you want
2. Insert another map, which I rename to be Overview Map, and configure it with the layers you want
3. Insert a layout
4. Insert a map frame onto the Layout using Main Map, and rename it to be Main Map Frame
5. Insert another map frame onto the Layout using Overview Map, and rename it to be Overview Map Frame
6. In the Layout click on the Overview Map Frame to make it active
7. On the Insert tab of the Ribbon use the Extent Indicator button to choose the Main Map Frame to be the extent indicated on the Overview Map Frame
8. If the rectangle shown on the Overview Map is hard to see use the Map Frame | Format ribbon to change it to something like a Stroke color of Mars Red and a line Width of 2 pts.

[image]

This workflow comes from [Making Maps and Map Series using ArcGIS Pro Layouts](https://www.udemy.com/course/making-maps-and-map-series-using-arcgis-pro-layouts/?referralCode=26DF74298F530DFCA6E9) which is an eLearning video course that goes into making various types of map series with main, overview, inset and index maps.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author and presenter of the course mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you @PolyGeo for your help. I already figured out how to get the extend indicator with your help. There is still one point missing: once is started the map series the extend indicator moves out of my overview map. So the extend indicator should stay in the middle of the overview mapframe, the extend of the overview mapframe moves. Its like to say "stay focused on the extend indicator, keep scale 1:50 000". If i put the whole map in its full extend in the overview map you wouldnt be able to see the extend indikator of the main map.

Answer (score 1):

In the layout view find your "Overview Map Frame" or which ever map frame you want to use as a dynamic locator inset. For me this is "Map Frame Local Indicator2".

[image]

Right click it and go to properties. Navigate to Display Options and from there under Constraint click the drop down and find "Linked map series center". Under Location Settings -> Scale set that to your 1:50,000. Mine is set to 1:54,000. That creates a fixed scale but other options under constraint allow for more dynamic scaling.

[image]